# count combinations in python

Tags: python, count, combinations, set

I have been puzzling for hours how to make a program for this problem. I searched for similar solutions but I had no success.

There are 6 sets of 2 values `a [a1,a2] ; b [b1, b2] ; ... f [f1, f2].`

Every combination needs to have at least one value from every set, but it can have also both. Therefore, there are 64 combinations.

What I need is to count all those combinations, and print something like this:

```
Combination 1: a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 Sum:  (sum of those listed)

Combination 2: ...

Total sum:
```

Comment: "Every combination needs to have at least one value from every set, but it can have also both." --> For me that results in 3^6 = 729 combinations. Lenghts vary from 6 to 12 elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from itertools import product   
>>> for item in product(['a1', 'a2'], ['b1', 'b2'], ['c1', 'c2']):
...     print item
...     
('a1', 'b1', 'c1')
('a1', 'b1', 'c2')
('a1', 'b2', 'c1')
('a1', 'b2', 'c2')
('a2', 'b1', 'c1')
('a2', 'b1', 'c2')
('a2', 'b2', 'c1')
('a2', 'b2', 'c2')
```

It looks like your a1, a2 etc are numeric. That's fine too

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> for item in product([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]):
...     print item, sum(item)
... 
(1, 3, 5) 9
(1, 3, 6) 10
(1, 4, 5) 10
(1, 4, 6) 11
(2, 3, 5) 10
(2, 3, 6) 11
(2, 4, 5) 11
(2, 4, 6) 12
```

Comment: thank you. this does what i wanted to do but doesn't solve my problem :( it seems that i need more combinations to compute this because there is possibility that both values are choosen.
ex: Combination 1: a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1 and comb 2: a1, a2, b1, b2, c1, c2, d1, d2, e1, e2, f1, f2 or any combination possible. So it can be 6 values, 7, 8 ... up to 12 but the condition is that it must contain at least one from every of 6 sets. Sorry that I explained it poorly

Comment: obviously that there are more combinations involved

Comment: @user2172096, sure I just put 3 pairs. You can extend it to 6 pairs with no other changes

Comment: I extended it on six pairs but it gives me all the combinations with no more than 6 values (one from each pair), while there is possibility that solution has 12 values (all values from all pairs) or six or seven.. It can be either a1 or a2 from set A but it can be both of them. Only that, there has to be at least one from any pair